# How to access TCP Flags by using c#

Tags: c#, tcp, flags

Where is the code example to use c# to access TCP flags? I only could find c language to do it.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: IP and TCP are bellow the application layer and is handled by the OS and network card. The only way to access these would be to write a filter driver or something similar. I do not think this is possible in c#, or at least not advisable. What is it you are really trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for replying, just want to detect the tcp falgs in my app.

Comment: Why? Why would the user care about that? Are you building a network packet inspection software? What is it you are actually trying to achieve by displaying TCP flags?